# Expo Location Permissions Instantly Denied iOS Simulator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ios-simulator, expo

When I do:

```
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';


export default function Screen() {
    Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION).then(function(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
    });
    return <View></View>;
};
```

The promise instantly resolves, and my access is denied without the application having asked me for permission to use location services:

```
Object {
  "expires": "never",
  "permissions": Object {
    "location": Object {
      "expires": "never",
      "granted": false,
      "ios": Object {
        "scope": "none",
      },
      "status": "denied",
    },
  },
  "status": "denied",
}
```

But if I run it on my iPhone instead of the simulator, the application actually asks for location permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the expo/your app has been in the simulator before and the location permission was not granted. The location permission dialog only shows once per app lifetime. Have you tried uninstalling the app?

Comment: Problem was fixed by doing "Erase all content and settings" in the iOS simulator. Uninstalling the app would probably achieve the same thing. Interesting that it only shows the dialog once per app life time, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Same happening with my device but nothing worked.